# How to delete , Null(""), from the end using Java

Tags: java, split

As the title of the question states: How can I remove `, Null(""),` from the String?
I have tried the following code, but it is not working:

```
String c = "customer_date, privacy_code, Null(""), ";  
String nd = "Null(\"\")";  
c = c.substring(0, c.lastIndexOf(nd));
```

Comment: You should ask yourself how you get the first string...? Is it the result of a .toString() call?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove it only from the end of the string, you can use [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
nd = nd.replaceAll("Null\\(\"\"\\),$", "");
```

Since it accepts a regex, I added the [`$`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) special character that matches the end of a string.

Please visit the [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to discover many useful methods that will help you.

Comment: Don't you need to escape the inner double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not compile if you don't use escape character , any way you dont have to trouble your self with quotes you can only  String nd = "Null"; instead like so

```
String c="customer_date, privacy_code, Null(\"\"), ";

      String nd = "Null";

      c=c.substring(0,c.lastIndexOf(nd));

      System.out.println(c);
```

because a piece of string youre trying to remove starts with NULL anyway

Answer (score 0):

I like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut!

```
String in = "customer_date, privacy_code, Null(\"\"), ";
String out = Arrays.asList(in.split(",")).stream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("Null(\"\")"))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```